# Aluminum tube frame to support 2300 lbs water tank

Tags: structural-engineering

I want to build an aluminum tube frame strong enough to support a 2300 lbs water tank. The dimensions of the frame would be 28 " wide, 72" long and 16 inches tall.
My intention is to use 2" x 2",  1/8 wall tube for the sides, back, and vertical supports.
However, on the front face i would like it open for a 'drawer step'  spanning the 75 inches. 
My question is what kind of aluminum tube could i use for a header across that face to support its share of the load.
I was considering 4" x 2" tube with 1/4 wall, installed on end, making a 4" header.  Would this suffice?

Is there more information i need to provide?

Thank you to anyone looking at my inquiry

Comment: I propose a sketch!

Answer (score 1):

What you're planning to do has lateral instability. It will collapse by rotation of one or both of the side walls.

You either need to brace all four sides with possibly 1.5 inch tube or on front use some short walls, say 12 inches wide by 16 tall, on each side to provide lateral stability, and possibly use 2.5 inch tube for the front top.

The best idea is to design and calculate the support for loads and apply 20% of that as lateral load and calculate for lateral support.

Answer (score 0):

Aluminum tube compressive strength by gauged wall thickness.
https://www.unifiedalloys.com/p/aluminum-copper-carbon-steel-tube-pressure-ratings/

It's pretty tough, better idea, just get a bunch of aluminum tubes like a pile of straws and bind them together